# How can I use a reactive filtered dataset within a gauge plot?

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

I'm relatively new to `shiny` and `flexdashboard`, but I'm trying to produce a gauge chart from a filtered dataset.

The goal is to filter a dataset on a variable (in the ReprEx it is `gear`), and then extract the lowest value in another variable from the filtered dataset (in the ReprEx, I want to find the lowest `mpg`).

First off, I select the input.

```
selectInput("x", "Gear", choices = mtcars$gear)
```

Then I'm currently creating a reactive dataset with a filter for gear in the sidebar.

```
df <- reactive({
  mtcars %>% filter(gear == input$x)
})
```

Finally I'm rendering the gauge plot, trying to extract the column `mpg` into a vector `x`, and then inputting the `min(x)` into the gauge chart.

```
renderPlot({
     x <- df()[,"mpg"]
gauge(min(x), min = 0, max = 50, gaugeSectors(
  success = c(41, 50), warning = c(21, 40), danger = c(0, 20)
))
})
```

Where in this process am I going wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `renderGauge` instead of `renderPlot`

[See Official Doc](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/flexdashboard/using.html#shiny-2)